# kotlin, what is better way to aggregate the result from a list of functions

Tags: list, kotlin

In kotlin.
Having a list of functions, every one returns true or false.
If one of the function returns true, then the final return should be true. Other wise return false.

What is the better way to write the kotlin function for it?

Having one function but feel it could be written better, any suggestion?

```
fun returnTheResultFromTheListOfFunctions(funcList: MutableList<FunctionType)
   return if (funcList.isEmpty()) {
            true
        } else {
            for (func in funcList) {
                if (func.getResult())
                    return true
            }
            false
        }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "better"?

Comment: What is `FunctionType`?

Comment: BTW, this is a digression, but it seems strange to me to return `true` for an empty list. If your logic is like "we need at least one item that meets the condition" then an empty list obviously doesn't match this requirement. This is why `any {}` by default return false for empty collections. Having said that, there are situations when such a logic is expected. For example if we have some kind of a search query that ORs its conditions and empty list is considered as "do not filter".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want true if the list is empty or `func.getResult()` is true for any element, so you can pretty directly convert the semantics to code:

```
return funcList.isEmpty() || funcList.any { it.getResult() }
```